# Create Custom View to improve performance

Tags: android, performance, gmail, android-custom-view

How to create customview for **listview** like gmail.
 
I have heard that gmail is used custom view using canvas for better performace. 

Suppose i have to develop gmail layout in normal way. i will use Relativelayouts, 2 imageviews, 5 to 6 textviews etc for single row of listview.

**Now this same layout gmail has develop with single customview.** 

[image]
i know how to create customview using textview and imageview. but to develop this kind of designs need more components.

Deep hierarchies need to develop this kind of layout.

**Is there any brife code which guide me?**

Answer (score 0):

You have to draw each element in canvas. Bitmap for image, and texts for each text. For more details: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html

Comment: any easy example which helps. Thanks